# How to conditionally remove characters (ex. "ed", "s" word endings) from observations in r

Tags: r, regex, nlp

I am scraping a word document to get the frequency of "content words" only. To this point, I have been able to use Tidyverse and Tidytext packages to remove words that are articles, include punctuation, have a length of one, etc with functions like:

```
!str_detect(word, pattern = "[[:digit:]]"), # removes any words with numeric digits
!str_detect(word, pattern = "[[:punct:]]"), # removes any remaining punctuations
!str_detect(word, pattern = "(.)\\1{2,}"),  # removes any words with 3 or more repeated letters
!str_detect(word, pattern = "\\b(.)\\b")    # removes any remaining single letter words
```

Now, I do not want to remove entire observations any longer--I want to remove only certain characters from existing observations (ex. remove "s" and "ed" endings)

Current Dataframe:

```
    print(df)

    WORD       N   
    Happy      7
    Apple      8
    Coworkers  16
    Customers  9
    Kicked     11
    Turtle     8
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
    WORD       N   
    Happy      7
    Apple      8
    Coworker   16
    Customer   9
    Kick       11
    Turtle     8
```

Comment: use general regex patterns. better performance is to use a proper stemmer.

Comment: Would you really want married->marri and sepsis->sepsi?

Comment: @qwr I would prefer to use a proper stemmer, to avoid issues pointed out by AdamO. Do you have a particular stem package/function in mind? Snowball and StopWord did not seem to remove characters as desired. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamO see above

Comment: @DavidLindhagen see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like

```
/\w+((s)|(ed))$/g
```

The `\w+` will match 1 or more alphabetic characters.

The `((s)|(ed))$` looks for an ending of either "s" or "ed". You can extend that list as needed.

The beginning and ending slashes aren't part of the regex, they just mark the beginning and end of the match pattern.

The final `g` after the last slash is a regex flag that indicates you want to match globally, which in most languages will mean that you don't just stop when you find the first match, it'll find all matches. This may not be appropriate in your case, you'll have to experiment to figure out if it's what you need.

Note that the beginning/ending slashes and the `g` is a syntax not used in every language, so I'm not sure whether it applies in R. Some languages have regex libraries that make you pass the flags in as separate arguments so read your language's documentation to figure out how that works.

Wrapping things in parentheses automatically creates capturing groups, so you can check the regex match object to see if the 1st capture group (corresponding to the outer parens) has a match, which tells you that this word has an ending you need to replace, then you can perform a regex replace using the first capture group and it'll get rid of any of those endings for you.

I recommend https://regex101.com to test your regular expressions while developing them. Here's a regex & test suite I saved pertaining to your question, if you want to use it: https://regex101.com/r/tBduP6/2

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to text analysis in r. Is this in the context of str_detect? !str_detect(word, pattern = "/\w+((s)|(ed))$/g")

Comment: I've never used R but regular expressions tend to be pretty consistent across languages. As for how to actually use them in R, this looks like it might be useful: https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: you may have to set regex to use perl mode. idk the exact differences.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex may work for simple cases (nouns, verbs) but for more accurate results I recommend a proper stemmer/lemmatizer. I've had good results with [spaCy's Lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer).

Here is a R wrapper to spaCy http://spacyr.quanteda.io/